# How to get previous revision CL in perforce

Tags: java, perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-branch-spec

I am writing a program, where i have the `CL` ,from which I need to access the previoius revision `CL` of each file.

How can I get it ?

Code I have written till now is:

```
IChangelist cl = server.getChangelist(clId);   
List<IFileSpec> files = cl.getFiles(true);  
for(int i = 0; i < files.size() ; i++) {  
    IFileSpec fileSpec=files.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need the previous changelist number for each file?  Why not just subtract 1 from the changelist number you have?  What are you trying to do?  If you actually need the specific changelist number that each file was last changed at, how about running `p4 filelog FILE1 FILE2 ...` and parsing the output?

Comment: file log may work,is there any java api which provides the file log ?

Answer (score 1):

Revision specifiers can help you here (see 'p4 help revisions').

In particular, the previous revision of each of those files is the file as of the previous changelist.

So, since clId is the changelist you care about, compute change `clPrev = (clId - 1)`, and then look for 'file@clPrev'.

Comment: So you saying ,I should check all the previous changelists? Because  i can thousands of changelist daily in that project. Doing clId-1 will take a lot of time. Is there any other way we can find out the previous versions directly ?It will be really helpfull if you can provide me a sample code snippet.

Comment: Just change the first line of your code to:

IChangelist cl = server.getChangelist(clId - 1);

so you're getting the previous changelist instead.

Comment: @sam what you suggesting is traversing all the previous CL and checking if it contains the exact file or not correct ?In that case if existing CLs are in large number (we have right now more thatn 10000)  that it will be big loop. I dont want that. But i dont see any other way so i ll have to go with this solution for now. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I might not be understanding your question correctly, but no, what Bryan suggested (and what I attempted to clarify) is literally just subtract one.  No "traversing" and "checking", just add "-1" to the code you've already written.  Two keystrokes should do it.  Given a revision from a particular changelist, all you need to do to get the previous revision is to subtract one.  If that's not what you're after, giving an example of what you're trying to do might help make it more clear.

Comment: @SamStafford lets say i have one CL#10 which contains file1,file2 changes, CL#9 contains changes in file3 and file4,CL#8 contains changes in file5 and file6 finally CL#7 contains changes in file1 and file7. Now if I want revision of file1,after CL#10 I should get CL#7. If i do CL-1 I would get CL#9 which does not contain file1 hence of no use.
Now the complexity is more if the current CL number is >100000. (sadly it my case). 
I hope now I am clear with my query.

Comment: If you use file1@9 as an argument to a Perforce command you will in fact get the previous revision -- i.e. you get the revision that was current as of changelist 9.  A particular changelist does not need to "contain" a file in order to be applied to it as a revision specifier.